# What CSS can I use to change the background color of an epub on a Nook HD?

Tags: epub, nook, css

I'm having a really hard time changing the background color of my epub on the Nook HD.

I've tried doing:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

(Not that I would actually use red, I just want to see a difference.)

Nothing.

I've tried putting a `div` around the whole thing, and doing something like:

```
#myDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And, that *almost* works, but it doesn't expand the whole way. There is still white areas at the top and bottom that just stay a white background. Also, once a page ends, it only covers up until there's no text.

I've tried a bunch of other things too, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Anyone have any ideas?

(And, yes, publisher's defaults is on.)

Comment: You must remeber that Kobo itself can have some CSS that is more important than yours (for example user pref.)

Answer (score 1):

well this looks like a html/css question the height percentage in the css also needs that its parent has height as well

so you can try this.

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
```

and use your #myDiv coloring.